# Cross Product Application

Tags: cross-product

I want to know where [Cross Product](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGyfiOqiR4s) is applicable in simple things around us... e.g. In Physics, If I go outside the house, I could see someone biking, the spinning wheel is an example of Angular Momentum.. How about Cross Product?

Comment: I think  you should ask this in [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The angular momentum of a wheel along its axle might be seen as related to the the sum of the cross-products of the spokes (radii) with the linear momenta (mass times velocity) of the bits of the tyre and rim the spokes connect to.

Comment: For example: The moment of a force, the Lorentz force, torque, and angular momentum involve Cross Product.

Answer (score 0):

[Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations), e.g., $$\nabla\times E=-{\partial B\over\partial t}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are two properties that make the cross product a useful operation.

The first is the fact that the modulus of the cross product of two vectors is the area of the parallelogram defined by these vectors and, generalizing, we can use it to find volumes of polyhedra (and many other applications).

The second is that the cross product is a vector orthogonal to the two starting vectors, and this is used in all situations in which we want express a vector orthogonal to two given vectors. in Physics there are many such vectors: the angular moment, the force on charge moving in a magnetic field, etc..( you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Applications))